# how can i get my function to go through the dictionary and check if the key exists when user inputs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get def create() to go through the global variable data{} and check if the username exists when the user inputs a username and password. I'm not able to do that because first its an empty dictionary and then I'm not sure how I can ask for username and password multiple times and still continue to check the dictionary. If the username is similar to the username in dictionary then I want the person to try again with new username and password.

```
data = {}
def store(stor, username, password):
    stor[username] = password


def create():
    for i in range(2):
        user = input("Username: ")
        pas = input("Password: ")
        for key in data:
            if user == key:
                print("Try Again")
                user = input("Username: ")
                pas = input("Password: ")
                store(data,user, pas)
            print (data)

create()
```

Comment: Use `in` operator: `user in data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, observe that `store` is only called if `user == key`:

```
        if user == key:
            print("Try Again")
            user = input("Username: ")
            pas = input("Password: ")
            store(data,user, pas)
```

So, names that are valid the first time are never stored.  Also, notice that, after asking for new `user` and `pas` values, they are stored *without* checking if the new `user` was already in `data` or not.  Both these issues are fixed in the following code:

```
data = {}
def store(stor, username, password):
    stor[username] = password   

def create():
    for i in range(2):
        user = input("Username: ")
        pas = input("Password: ")
        while user in data:
            print("Try Again")
            user = input("Username: ")
            pas = input("Password: ")
        store(data,user, pas)
        print (data)

create()
```

In the revised code, a `while` loop is used that will keep asking for a new user name until one is given that is not in `data`.  New values are stored only after it is verified that `user` is not already in `data.